# Spring @Autowired and bean declaration in applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring

Hi I am relatively new to spring. Am using Annotations.
My doubt begin I have a class 
as

```
public class MyClassA{

@Autowired
private MyClassB variableClassB;

// more code here
.
.
.
```

in my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package containing MyClassB" />
```

My question being do I need to add bean declaration in applicationContext.xml as follows

```
<bean id="classB" class="com.MyClassB"
```

or is it sufficient to have @Autowired annotation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not.

If your `MyClassB` is annotated with annotations like `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository` or `@Controller` the component scan will create a bean for the class in the bean factory.

If you are not using any of these annotations then, you need to create a bean manually as you have given

Ex:

```
@Component
public class MyClassB{
}
```

Comment: NO I don't have any of these annotations. Its just a POJO class. So I guess I need to define a bean in applicationContext.xml. Right?

Comment: @Aditya yes you need to

Comment: There are many SO questions about the resulting error, but none suggest using @Component on the entity.  And thus none of them solved my problem.  I had to change my google search terms to `autowired bean declaration` in order to find this posting, with your answer that solved my problem.  Thank you and +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Annotation `@Component` on `MyClassB`, it's no need to add `<bean id="classB" class="com.MyClassB"` in applicationContext.xml. Otherwise, needed.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of the `@Autowired` annotation is just to avoid explicitly mentioning the bean in the `xml` file. Doing

`<context:component-scan base-package="package containing MyClassB" />`

checks the package and searches for the annotations `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository` etc and makes the bean itself.

Comment: NO I don't have any of these annotations. Its just a POJO class.
So I guess I need to define a bean in applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Autowired` annotation lets you avoid having to explicitly state the need for `MyClassB` in the XML declaration of `MyClassA`, but it does not mean that the `MyClassB` *bean* is created automatically.  If you don't want to have `MyClassB` appearing in the XML at all, you need to do a `context:component-scan` to find the `@Bean` (and derived) annotations. (The scan is fairly expensive, so you need to ask for it explicitly.)